# Write list to file txt(utf-8)

Tags: python

I tried to write a list to txt file with the encoding utf-8 without BOM. But have a problem is: 
If i create that file with utf-8 withou BOM encoding:

```
  ポ
  1
  田
  11
  直
  11
  子
  11
```

and use my function to read it to a list:

```
import codecs
def file_to_list(file_name):
    results = []
    f = codecs.open(file_name, encoding='utf-8')
    for line in f:
        results.append(line.replace('\r\n', ''))
    return results
list_1 = file_to_list('test_read.txt')
print(list_1)
```

I got the ok result : `['ポ', '1', '田', '11', '直', '11', '子', '11']`
But after this i using another function to write back to file and read that file again, a problem appear:

```
def list_to_file(file_name, thelist):
    f = codecs.open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    for item in thelist:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
list_to_file('test_read.txt', list_1)
list_2 = file_to_list('test_read.txt')
print(list_2)
```

the return of print is :`['ポ\n', '1\n', '田\n', '11\n', '直\n', '11\n', '子\n', '11\n']`
So, what wrong to make `'\n'`?

Comment: `line.replace('\r\n', '')` doesn't touch the plain `'\n'` bytes written by `list_to_file`. BTW, you should always mention the Python version with Unicode questions, since Py2 and Py3 have major differences in Unicode handling. Also, a UTF-8 encoded file should _never_ start with a BOM unless its required by some broken software that you're forced to use.

Comment: @PM2Ring can you teach me how to remove it?

Comment: You should try Moses' answer! You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be replacing trailing whitespaces/new line characters as they may vary across platforms. You should *strip* them. More so, you're writing to the file with only `\n`, but your function expects `\r\n`.

In your `file_to_list` function, replace:

```
results.append(line.replace('\r\n', ''))
```

with

```
results.append(line.rstrip())
```

---

See:

```
>>> 'some line\n'.replace('\r\n', '')
'some line\n'
```